# How does rust make a decision on what macro branch to use?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Consider the following code-snippet

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! test {
    ($a:literal) => { $a };
    ($a:expr) => { $a };
}

fn func() {
    let a = test!(0);
    let b = test!(a);
    let c = test!(-a);
}
```

Why does the third assignment not work? For some reason due to the `-` (I think) it fails in the first macro-branch. I would have expected it to use the second. Why isn't that the case?

I get the following error message:

```
error: unexpected token: `a`
   --> src/gate.rs:144:20
    |
137 |     ($a:literal) => { $a };
    |      ---------- while parsing argument for this `literal` macro fragment
...
144 |     let c = test!(-a);
    |                    ^
```

Edit: Adding parentheses around `-a` does make it work, although it then gives the warning:

```
warning: unnecessary parentheses around assigned value
   --> src/gate.rs:144:19
    |
144 |     let c = test!((-a));
    |                   ^^^^ help: remove these parentheses
    |
    = note: `#[warn(unused_parens)]` on by default
```

Comment: This is just a hunch: The parser enters the `literal` branch because the "-" character matches as a token for a literal (think "-5"); it then gets trapped because "a" can't be part of any literal that starts with "-"; it does not evaluate the other branches before erroring out. The parentheses force the `expression` branch to be taken because parentheses are not part of any literal.

Comment: That's really strange, looks like a bug to me. I might suggest opening an issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: Looking at the docs it indeed seems like a bug since "Note that the Rust syntax considers -1i8 as an application of the unary minus operator to an integer literal 1i8, rather than a single integer literal.". I'll open an issue

Comment: See [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82968)